# Evaluate $\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{t^2dt}{(t^2+1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Here's how I proceeded:

Set $f(z) := \frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^2}$, $g(t):=\frac{t^2}{(t^2+1)^2}$.

$(z^2+1)^2=[(z+i)(z-i)]^2$, so $f(z)$ has poles of order $2$, and the singular points are $i$ and $-i$. Now one needs to find the residue at $i$ in order to evaluate this integral over the contour of radius $R$, located in the upper half of the complex plane, as well as on the real line from $R$ to $-R$.

The question is: how to find the residue at $i$?

$Res_{z=i}[f(z)]=\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{d}{dz}(z-i)^2 \frac{z^2}{[(z-i)(z+i)]^2}=2\lim\limits_{z\to i}(z-i) \frac{z^2}{[(z-i)(z+i)]^2}=2\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{z^2}{(z-i)(z+i)^2} $

But here's where I get stuck. Would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: You want complex analysis, but we can solve all integrals of rational functions with partial fractions. Writing the integrand as $$\frac{1}{t^2 + 1} - \frac{1}{(t^2 + 1)^2}$$

and using the known formula, easy to prove, $$\int \frac{dt}{(t^2 + a^2)^m} = \frac{t}{2a^2(m-1)(t^2 + a^2)^{m-1}} + \frac{2m-3}{2a^2(m-1)} \int \frac{dt}{(t^2 + a^2)^{m-1}}$$

This implies the indefinite integral is 
$$\frac 12\left(\arctan x - \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}\right)$$

Letting $x \to \infty$ yields the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake at the derivative. Note that $$\left(\frac{z^2}{(z+i)^2}\right)' = \frac{2z(z+i)^2-2z^2(z+i)}{(z+i)^4}=\frac{2zi}{(z+i)^3}.$$ Hence the residue you want is $\frac{1}{4i}$.

Comment: @sequence. Note that the polynomial term that is responsible for your poles, being $(z-i)^2$ is "taken out" of your given function, before the derivative is taken...

Answer (score 2):

By integration by parts
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2}{(t^2+1)^2}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t}{2}\cdot\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}},$$
hence the problem is quite trivial, with or without complex analytic techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I've made the same error once, because I applied the theorem wrong.

The theorem is as follows:

> Let $z_0$ be a pole of order $N$ of a function $f$, then
>   $$\mathop{\text{res}}_{z=z_0} f(z) = \frac{1}{(N-1)!}\cdot \lim_{z\to z_0}\left((z-z_0)^N f(z) \right)^{(N-1)}$$

Notice how the derivative is taken on the function $(z-z_0)^N f(z)$, the $(z-z_0)^N$ multiplication takes care of the singularity.

Btw, Wolfram supports residue calculation:

```
residue of z^2/(z^2+1)^2 at z=i
```

Results in $\frac{-i}{4}$